# OS considerations with regard to Package management

Tags: linux, windows, npm, bower, package-managers

I'm doing research to decide which technology I should use for a web development project.

One of the considerations is package management. I'll probably end up using NPM or bower or something.

Are particular operating systems (eg: centos vs windows) better suited to handling package management?

Answer (score 1):

This belongs to superuser or serverfault.Anyways

pacman: packages contain everything related to them. no install/uninstall scripts embedded

debian: packages have a dozen kinds of scripts. they have signatures. and do only one thing/contain one part of a program

rpm: there is no actual central repository, no signature, some install scripts. tad bit messy

ebuild/aur/...: You shouldn't even know these names unless you know exactly what you're doing.

tar.*: you're on your own.

**Edit**: oh, uh, uh. ouch. It was NPM, not RPM. if you think this is unrelated just say so, I'll delete it.

Comment: not unrelated actually

Comment: I'm going to need a variety of package managers here. I don't want to end up in package management hell

Comment: You trying to decide how to install packages on the server or the client machine?

Comment: both server and client.

Comment: In my little experience you should go with static linking and/or shipping your own libraries if the application is proprietary. otherwise distribution maintainers will take care of it for you.